# Calculating the record value

Tags: mysql

I have two table one tblstationerystock (stationery_name,stationery_code, balance) and other tblstationerytranscation(stationery_code,trsntype,quantity).Trsntype column is transction type consists of two type of value (received or issued)
I want to calculate the value of balance in first table based on any transcation for stationery in second table.
Mathematically suppose there is  a stationery name 'PEN' in first table and in second table  there are three record for stationery 'PEN' -
STATIONERY. TRSNTYPE   QUANTITY
Pen.        Received.     200
Pen.        Issued.         30
Pen.        Issued.         40

In first table in balance column it should show 50(100-30-20)

I dont have much knowledge about sql .Is it possiblePlease guide me to achieve this .
[image]

Comment: Check [mcve] for guidance on creating a good question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if the MySQL version supports, you can use an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER

Here is the code that will help for INSERT statements

```
    delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger 
    AFTER INSERT 
ON tblstationerytranscation 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    declare quan integer;
    set quan = new.quantity;

    if new.trsntype = 'issued' then 
        set quan = -1 * quan;
    END IF;
    
        update tblstationerystock 
        SET balance = balance + quan
        where stationery_code =  new.stationery_code;

end $$
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is new.stationery_code in your solution

Comment: In your question, the table tblstationerytranscation has the field stationery_code not as stationerycode as in the screenshot. That is the foreign key field in your table referincing to the tblstationerystock  table